# How to split/subset tabular data by column values

Tags: r, split, subset

Hello and thanks for reading.  I am using rStudio v3.1.2 on a Windows 7 OS.

I am working on a Coursera project which in short, requires me to write a function that takes two arguments: the 2-character abbreviated name of a state and an outcome name.  Both of these arguments denote to specific columns in my data which I must subset, order and return a character vector with the name of the hospital that has the best (i.e. lowest) 30-day mortality for the specified outcome in that state.  More details about the assignment can be found at the following link:
http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/2104_db4f612f1f2c477b91c8a456fb014c9e.html

I am running into problems attempting to subset only the data relevant to the state in question.  The rest of the necessary code doesn't throw an error and produces expected results, so for the sake of not posting code that could be plagiarized I will only introduce my version of accomplishing the task at hand.

```
## subset only data with specific state
   dataSlice <- subset(data, data$State == state)
   head(dataSlice)
## I've also tried
   dataSlice <- subset(data, state %in% data$State)
   head(dataSlice)
```

When I call the function with:

```
best("TX","heart attack")
```

Both results seem to give me the first 6 rows of every column from "AL" and not "TX", which leads me to believe that the data didn't subset at all and I am just getting the first 6 lines of `data` (the entire data.frame before attempted subset).  I would post results but there are 47 columns and 6 rows from each would overwhelm the page certainly.

First and foremost, I want to understand why this result is produced because it seems to make zero sense to me.  If after that, adjusting my code can produce expected results, how might I be able to rewrite it?

Comment: Since data$State already == state (all states), no subset per se was performed.  If rather you assist subset with some information:  dataSlice <- subset(data, data$State == "TX") for instance would probably get you out of Alabama. That being said, you're going to be doing this inside a function where subset can perform at times unpredictably, so you might be better using dataSlice <- data[data$V19 == "TX" (for rows), (and whatever condition your looking for -"heart attack" etc, as data$V? == "heart attack" (for columns)]. You'll have to adjust those V's relative to your data

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I suppose my only issue with this answer is that I feel like I actually do define what value `state` is in my function call.  If the definition (excuse my java syntax) is `best <- function(state, outcome)` and I call `best("TX", "heart attack")`  am I not essentially saying `dataSlice <- subset(data, data$State == "TX")` when the code says `dataSlice <- subset(data, data$State == state)` ?

Comment: best <- function(state,outcome) {

Comment: best <- function(state,condition) { dataSlice <-data[data$V19 == state, data$V(the condition column) == condition] perhaps, then sort/rank, return(dataSlice)} ? some such. Hard to tell not knowing what else you have in your function.Subset Warning: This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions like ‘[’ from the subset help.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I've resolved the issue after heeding your warning and discarding `subset` entirely.